# Given $G$ finite and $L(G)=G$ where $L(G)=\{g\in G\;|\;\alpha(g)=g, \forall \alpha\in \textrm{Aut}(G)\}$ . Prove that $G=1$ or $G=\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Given $G$ finite and $L(G)=G$ where $L(G)=\{g\in G\;|\;\alpha(g)=g, \forall \alpha\in \textrm{Aut}(G)\}$
 Prove that if $L(G)=G$, then $G=1$ or $G=\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Here I already proved that $L(G)\leq Z(G)$.
So we can know that $G$ is abelian.

Suppose that $G\neq 1$. I want to prove that $G=\mathbb{Z}_2$

Definite $\beta:G\rightarrow G$ by $\beta(g)=g^{-1}$.
Since $G$ is abelian, $\beta\in \textrm{Aut}(G)$.

Let $x\in G$ where $x\neq 1$.
Then we have $x=\beta(x)=x^{-1}$ which implies that $x^2=1$.
So up to here, I proved that all the elements other than identity must have order 2.

But how can I show that all the other elements must equal to $x$ or $1$?

Comment: Add an element $y$, and you get another element $xy$, both of order $1$. Can you construct an automorphism which contradicts the above condition?

Comment: If I let an element $y$ where $y\neq 1,x$. Then $xy$ should be of order 2 right? @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: It will be right? $(xy)^2 = x^2y^2 = 1$, where $y^2=1$.

Comment: Err i can't get your idea in the first comment. Do you mean that add an element $y$ such that the order of $xy$ is 1 and we get a contradiction? @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: Exactly. See, I am attempting to contradict the fact that there are only two elements, and adding one more random element $y$ of order $2$, which makes $xy$ of order $2$. Now, I want you to show that $L(G)$ can't be $G$. How you do this, is find an element such that not all automorphisms fix it. This amounts to finding some non-trivial automorphism of that ring. For example, consider the automorphism $\alpha$ given by $\alpha(x)=y,\alpha(y)=xy,\alpha(xy)=x$. Check that this is an automorphism fixing  no elements other than $1$, hence $L(G) \neq G$. This is our contradiction, and the result.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x^2 = 1$ for every $x \in G$ and $G$ is abelian, it is actually a vector space over field $\mathbb{F}_2$. Unless it's dimension is $1$, it has non-trivial automorphisms.

Comment: You mean a vector space.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Of course, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solution may be sortened in that way.

Assume that $G\neq 1$. Then $Aut(G)$ act trivially on $G$. Thus, $Aut(G)=1$. Hence, $G$ is abelian. If $|G|=n$ then assume $Gcd(n,k)=1$. Then notice that $f(g)=g^k$ is an automorphism. Since $Aut(G)=1$, $\Phi(n)=1 \implies n=2.$